# how to set session variable and validation both together on same button in php

Tags: php, validation, session

I'm a newbie in php. I want to validate a form and set the form data to the session variables so as to use them onto next page.
here is the code,

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function val(){
    var n=document.f.cname.value;
    if(n==""||n==null){
        alert("Please enter name field.");
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="<?php $_Php_SELF?>" onsubmit="return val()">
name : <input type="text" name="cname" />
<input type="Submit" name="submit" value="Sub"/>
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $_SESSION['caname']=$_POST['cname'];
    header("location:sessiontest2.php");
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

The second page just echos the session variable.
Without validation it works fine.

Comment: why don't you just submit the form to `sessiontest2.php` (=the 'action')? (Note: You can still validate in js as you do)

Comment: What is the problem now? What happens _with_ validation?

Comment: it wasn't validating and redirected to next page with empty session variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Handle your redirection before the html part. Also fixed your code.

```
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $_SESSION['caname'] = $_POST['cname'];
    header("location:sessiontest2.php");
}
?>
<html>
<body>
<form name="myForm" method="post" action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" onsubmit="return validate()">
    Name : <input type="text" name="cname"/>
    <input type="Submit" name="submit" value="Sub"/>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function validate() {
        var name = document.forms["myForm"]["cname"].value;

        if(name.length === 0){
            alert("Please enter the name");
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why did we replace $_Php_SELF with $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?

Comment: Because it's been deprecated and removed in new versions of PHP. `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` does what it used to do.

Answer (score 0):

The

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $_SESSION['caname']=$_POST['cname'];
    header("location:sessiontest2.php");
}
```

has to be at the top of the page after the `session_start()`, because the header function must be called before html is printed out.

Other than that it looks fine.